# UAC Behaviour in PRACK implementation

Tags: sip

The 200 OK of the PRACK is received later at the UAC than the 200 OK of the INVITE provided that the UAS had sent them in proper order..what should be the behavior of the UAC? Will it silently drop the packet? Or will it establish the dialog ?

Comment: in UDP land, it is possible for the UAS implementation to be correct, yet the two 200 OKs (to PRACK and INVITE) still arrive in reversed order. Such a normal event should not impact dialog establishment.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in standard that somehow bounds 200 OK for INVITE and 200  OK for PRACK on the client side. UAC should handle 2xx response to INVITE according to

RFC 3261 - 13.2.2.4 2xx Responses

> Multiple 2xx responses may arrive at the UAC for a single INVITE
>   request due to a forking proxy.  Each response is distinguished by
>   the tag parameter in the To header field, and each represents a
>   distinct dialog, with a distinct dialog identifier.
>
> If the dialog identifier in the 2xx response matches the dialog
>   identifier of an existing dialog, **the dialog MUST be transitioned to
>
>   the "confirmed" state**, and the route set for the dialog MUST be
>   recomputed based on the 2xx response using the procedures of Section
>      12.2.1.2.  Otherwise, a new dialog in the "confirmed" state MUST be    constructed using the procedures of Section 12.1.2.

And it has to handle response to PRACK based on RFC 3262

> Note that the PRACK is like any other non-INVITE request within a
>      dialog.

There is requirement for UAS

> The UAS MAY send a final response to the initial request before
>      having received PRACKs for all unacknowledged reliable provisional
>      responses, **unless the final response is 2xx** and any of the
>      unacknowledged reliable provisional responses contained a session
>      description.  In that case, **it MUST NOT send a final response** until
>      those provisional responses are acknowledged.

So it would seem that UAC receiving 2xx response could decide that UAS has received the PRACK and stop its retransmissing - But there is nothing like that stated in the RFC. So even after receiving 2xx response to the INVITE UAC should continue retransmitting PRACK till it is acknowledged.